# Colocar div filha de elemento ul li ocupando 100% da largura da página

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, front-end, div

O problema é o seguinte: eu tenho uma div que é filha de um elemento li de um ul que não começa no canto da página. Há dois subproblemas:

1 - Eu preciso conseguir expandir essa div de modo que ela ocupe a largura toda da página independente de resolução.

2 - Eu preciso que ela sempre ocupe a largura quando eu dou scroll.

Estrutura:

```html
Estrutura:
     <ul class="main-menu">
      <li class="menu-item nossos-hoteis">
    <a class="menu-link" href=""><span>Nossos Hotéis</span></a>
       <div class="submenu">
      </li>
     </ul>
```

CSS:

/* submenu */

```
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: 872px;
height: 500px;
padding: 20px 30px;
```

/* main-menu */

```
.main-nav .main-menu {
   display: none;
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

/* menu-item */

```
.main-nav .main-menu>.menu-item {
   display: table-cell;
   height: inherit;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 0 15px;
}
```

A solução que eu estava tentando até o momento era gambiarrada demais que era botar a div com a largura da tela em JQUERY e definir left negativo a depender faixa de resolução. Resolve, resolve o 1 mas eu penso que talvez possa existir solução melhor até porque quando eu dou scroll na tela por estar sendo definido um left manual a div deixa de ocupar a tela toda.

Comment: Estrutura:
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="submenu">

CSS:
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 872px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 20px 30px;

Comment: Seja bem-vinda, poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/254115/edit) sua pergunta e colocar esse código nela ? Para formatar o código basta selecionar ele e apertar a tecla de atalho `CTRL+K`, aproveite e faça o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Para obter uma resposta adequada deve incluir na pergunta o CSS que tanto o `<ul>` como o `<li>` tem, o que já de certa forma irá tornar o código da pergunta num exemplo verificável do problema.

Comment: Aí é complicado, porque essa div está dentro de uma UL que não está no canto da tela. Acho que só vai na base de um tratamento (da gambiarra) via jQuery mesmo.

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta você quer que a div `submenu` ocupe toda a largura da janela de visualização, correto? Fiz de maneira bem simples, sem JavaScript/jQuery, com o seguinte css:

```
.submenu {
    position: absolute;  
    width: calc(100vw + 15px);
    left: -15px;
}
```

Passei para o `submenu` que ele inicie a menos 15px (`padding` da `ul`) e que ele ocupe cem por cento do `viewport width` (largura da janela de visualização) mais os 15px movidos. Você pode ver como ficou em um exemplo abaixo:

```css
.submenu {
  position: absolute;  
  width: calc(100vw + 15px);
  left: -15px;
  
  /* Apenas para ser visto */
  height: 100px;
  background: navy;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li class="menu-item nossos-hoteis">
    <a class="menu-link" href=""><span>Nossos Hotéis</span></a>
    <div class="submenu"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```